# Rails 5.1 - React - React Burger Menu Not displaying

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have Rails 5.1 app and am trying to use [this burger menu](https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu) through react. I have the basic example setup but my rails render content shows up for just a second, then the react burger menu component seems to overrule it and makes it go away.
Here is the react menu burger component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { push as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'

var styles = {
...
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  showSettings (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Menu styles={ styles } >
        <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
        <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
      </Menu>
    );
  }

}
render(<Example />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is my body from rails main page.

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <div id="outer-container">
    <header>I am a fixed header!</header>
  <Menu pageWrapId={ "page-wrap" } outerContainerId={ "outer-container" } />
  <main id="page-wrap">
    <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/nav' %>
    <div class="content">
        <%= yield %>    
    </div>
    <%= render '/shared/footer' %>
  </main>
</div>
</div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'navbar' %>
</body>
```

The fixed header, the renders, and the yield ERB are not showing up after the react JS loads. Any ideas about why?
Thank you, and sorry I am new to Rails 5.1 and react, so just trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe,
You need to fill out your styles as well.  I don't know if you tried it without styles or not but put this info in there and you'll see it appear in your browser.  You can find the rest of the styles snippet at the bottom of the instructions for react-burger-menu.  You also need to close the `<div id="app"></div>` right after instead of at the end of the content.

```
var styles = {
  bmBurgerButton: {
    position: "fixed",
    width: "36px",
    height: "30px",
    left: "36px",
    top: "36px"
  },
  bmBurgerBars: {
    background: "#373a47"
  },
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: The "..." in my styles section means the styles are there - I just eliminated them from the question to make it more readable. With or without the styles, the rendering problem still exists. Any other ideas?

Comment: I put your react code into codesandbox and it shows the burger icon so i'm assuming something inside rails code might be the issue.

Comment: Good call on the sandbox. I did this as well and realized I needed to close the <div id="app"> right away instead of after the other content. The answer is <div id="app"></div>. If you answer this question, I will accept it. Cheers. Thanks for your help.